# when I use the cut command, I get a result that is not expected

Tags: linux, shell, cut

there is my script:

```
table_nm=$1
hive_db=$(echo $table_nm | cut -d'.' -f1)
hive_tb=$(echo $table_nm | cut -d'.' -f2)
```

At first, I got the right result:

```
$echo "dev.dmf_bird_cost_detail" | cut -d'.' -f1
dev   #correct
$echo "dev.dmf_bird_cost_detail" | cut -d'.' -f2
dmf_bird_cost_detail   #correct
```

but,i got something is wrong,if there is no specified character in $table_nm, I get this result：

```
$echo "dmf_bird_cost_detail" | cut -d'.' -f1
dmf_bird_cost_detail   
$echo "dmf_bird_cost_detail" | cut -d'.' -f2
dmf_bird_cost_detail  
$echo "dmf_bird_cost_detail" | cut -d'.' -f3
dmf_bird_cost_detail
```

The result that is not I expected, i hope it's empty, so i conducted some tests and  found that if there is no specified character in the string, the command "cut" will return the original value, is that true?

At last,i know "awk" will solves my problem, but I would like to know why "cut" has the above result?
Thank you guys so much!

Comment: By default with the field option, everything is printed if no delimiter exists. There used to be a `-s` (`--only-delimited`) option, which prevented this but I can't get it to work on my box. You may have better luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [POSIX cut specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html):

> -f  list
>
> [...] Lines with no field delimiters shall be passed through intact, unless -s is specified. [...]

> why "cut" has the above result?

My guess would be that the first implementations of `cut` had such behavior (my guess would be it was a bug), and it was preserved and POSIX standardized existing behavior and added `-s` option. You can browse https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl for some old verison of `cut`.

Comment: Yeah!Thank you very much for your answer .So the best way is that i add `-s` option.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is probably to use a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) anyway.

```sh
hive_db=${table_nm%.*}
hive_tb=${table_nm#"$hive_db".}
```

If you expect more than one dot, you need some additional processing to extract the second field.

Because this uses shell built-ins, it is a lot more efficient than spawning two processes for each field you want to extract (and even then you should [use proper quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)).